# Why does the C++ standard not prohibit such a dreadful usage?

Tags: c++11, bind, pass-by-value

The source code is very simple and self-evident. The question is included in the comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        cout << "A::ctor" << endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        cout << "A::dtor" << endl;
    }

    void foo()
    {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    /*
    Performance penalty!!!

    The following line will implicitly call A::dtor SIX times!!! (VC++ 2010)    
    */
    bind(&A::foo, a)();  

    /*
    The following line doesn't call A::dtor.

    It is obvious that: when binding a member function, passing a pointer as its first 
    argument is (almost) always the best way. 

    Now, the problem is: 

    Why does the C++ standard not prohibit bind(&SomeClass::SomeMemberFunc, arg1, ...) 
    from taking arg1 by value? If so, the above bind(&A::foo, a)(); wouldn't be
    compiled, which is just we want.
    */
    bind(&A::foo, &a)(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember there is a third alternative : `bind(&A::foo, std::ref(a))();`

Comment: @icecrime: I know. But I just wonder why does the C++ standard not explicitly prohibit such a dreadful and useless usage?

Comment: From view of the implementation, there are several overloaded bind functions, one of these takes its first argument by value. If the implementation doesn't provide such an overloaded function. then the aim is easily achieved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, there is a third alternative to your code :

```
bind(&A::foo, std::ref(a))();
```

Now, why are parameters taken by copy by default ? I presume, but it's just a wild guess, that it is considered preferable for `bind` default behavior to be independent of the parameters lifetime : the result of a bind is a functor of which invocation could be delayed long after parameters destruction.

Would you expect from the following code  to yield UB *by default* ?

```
void foo(int i) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    std::function<void ()> f;

    {
        int i = 0;
        f = std::bind(foo, i);
    }

    f(); // Boom ?
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your convincing "wild guess".

Answer (score 0):

The mandate of C++ is not to make it impossible, or even harder, to write slow code. It is merely to require you to request the bells and whistles explicitly.

Comment: Making it harder to incorrectly use something is usually considered good design

Comment: True; but many people would find it hard to believe C++ is designed at all, let alone designed well ;)

Comment: well, those people are ignorant then. C++ is both. It is just designed under some unusual constraints, which require some pretty awkward tradeoffs. But (nearly) every wart and weird trade-off in C++ is there for a reason